# Texture doesn't seem to apply to this model

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to work this model:
https://opengameart.org/content/undead-male

When I open the model the textures provided are not applied. I select the face, arms and leg and go into the UV Editing tab where I add a texture. It looks like the model is unwrapped correctly on the texture, but the model still is just showing it's base color. I know I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve success by selecting each the body and head, respectively, and opening a Shading Editing window. From here, I checked the "Use Nodes" box, and added an image texture, mapped to the UV coordinates.

[image: Nodes]